# Text displaying on wrong line in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have some code to display a logo at the bottom of my page:

[image: It looks like this in Chrome]

Unfortunately, in IE (9, compatibility mode on or off), it looks like this:

[image: It looks like this in IE]

The only part I'm really worried about is the text being in the wrong place.

Here's the code:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" id="kwiiusIMG" height="50"/><br /><br />
<p class="kText">A Kwiius.com service by Jamie McClymont</p>
```

CSS:

```
#kwiiusIMG {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 305px;
}

.kText {
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666666;
}
```

Sorry, I'm a bit of an idiot when it comes to this stuff. Any idea how I could get IE working right?

Comment: So were any of the answers helpful? Let us know which answer you went with. Thanks!

Comment: @magzalez Sorry, SO wouldn't let me accept for 10 minutes, and I forgot about it. Done.

Comment: Still no accepted answer. Did you get everything figured out?

Comment: @magzalez - Whoops, SO is playing tricks with my mind. Quite often I accept an answer, but it cancels after I close the page. Done... I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing the float. I used to do something like this (code is not tested):

```
<img src="img/logo.png" id="kwiiusIMG" height="50"/>
<br />
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<br />
<p class="kText">A Kwiius.com service by Jamie McClymont</p>
```

I don't know the whole design, but I guess the float: left in #kwiiusIMG is not needed at all.

Comment: While you're both at it, you can also totally eliminate the `<br>`'s and adjust spacing via CSS.  Also like the other answer, you can simply add `clear: both;` to the CSS for `.kText` and get rid of the extra `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding more HTML markup, you can add this to the existing CSS for .kText

```
.KText {
clear: both;
}
```

This also avoids adding any inline CSS.

Edit: I should also have mentioned, as sparky672 points out below, this makes the break tags unnecessary. They should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make display block on your image as well and remove the float left:

```
#kwiiusIMG {
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-left: 305px;
    display: block;
}

.kText {
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #666666;
}​​
```